# Adding Entity into its own block in DraftJS

Tags: reactjs, wysiwyg, draftjs

So I'm trying to create a fairly simple WYSIWYG BBCode editor for my project as an opportunity to wrap my mind around DraftJS. I've been following some tutorials and also using [react-rte](https://github.com/sstur/react-rte) as an example (since it has 99% of the functionality I need and looks relatively simple to understand).

The problem I've stumped on is that `react-rte` inserts image entities inline (it adds a space in the current selection and then ties an entry to that space) like this:

```js
const addEntity = (editorState, type, mutability = 'MUTABLE', data = {}) => {
    let currentContent = editorState.getCurrentContent();
    let selection = editorState.getSelection();
    currentContent = currentContent.createEntity(type, mutability, data);
    let entityKey = currentContent.getLastCreatedEntityKey();
    return Modifier.insertText(currentContent, selection, ' ', null, entityKey);
}
```

I want each image (and video alike) to be in its own separate block and make it so nothing else can be written to that block.
I have found an example of the behavior I'm after in [megadraft](http://megadraft.io), but I have been unable to work my way through its code to find the correct implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution after many hours of trial and error (and lots of manuals).

```js
const addAtomic = (editorState, type, mutability = 'MUTABLE', data = {}) => {
    let currentContent = editorState.getCurrentContent();
    let selection = editorState.getSelection();
    currentContent = currentContent.createEntity(type, mutability, data);
    let entityKey = currentContent.getLastCreatedEntityKey();
    const newState = EditorState.set(editorState, { currentContent: currentContent })
    return AtomicBlockUtils.insertAtomicBlock(newState, entityKey, ' ')
}
```